# Java 8 stream - sort by max duplicates descending

Tags: java, java-8

Using Java 8 stream,
I am trying to sort a list by a part of the field (groupname) maximum duplicates descending.

It only needs to use the first part before : the second part is not relevant. And the unique row records order is not relevant. 
(I am only trying to bring the duplicate records to top according to max duplicates.)

**Test Data:**

```
100 : 200
200 : 207
200 : 203
200 : 201
300 : 202
103 : 201
103 : 202
```

**Expected:**

```
200 : 207
200 : 203
200 : 201
103 : 201
103 : 202
100 : 200
300 : 202
```

I tried the below code, it returns the orders correctly. But only the grouped data instead of the original full records and sorted.

```
200=3
103=2
100=1
300=1
```

**Java code**

```
@Test
public void testSplit2Optimsation() {

    List<CompatibilityRule> rules = new ArrayList<>();
    CompatibilityRule compatibilityRule1 = new CompatibilityRule();
    compatibilityRule1.setGroupname("100 : 200");

    CompatibilityRule compatibilityRule2 = new CompatibilityRule();
    compatibilityRule2.setGroupname("200 : 207");

    CompatibilityRule compatibilityRule3 = new CompatibilityRule();
    compatibilityRule3.setGroupname("200 : 203");

    CompatibilityRule compatibilityRule4 = new CompatibilityRule();
    compatibilityRule4.setGroupname("200 : 201");

    CompatibilityRule compatibilityRule5 = new CompatibilityRule();
    compatibilityRule5.setGroupname("300 : 202");

    CompatibilityRule compatibilityRule6 = new CompatibilityRule();
    compatibilityRule6.setGroupname("102 : 202");

    CompatibilityRule compatibilityRule7 = new CompatibilityRule();
    compatibilityRule7.setGroupname("103 : 202");

    rules.add(compatibilityRule1);
    rules.add(compatibilityRule2);
    rules.add(compatibilityRule3);
    rules.add(compatibilityRule4);
    rules.add(compatibilityRule5);
    rules.add(compatibilityRule6);
    rules.add(compatibilityRule7);



    rules.stream()
            .map(r -> r.getGroupname().split(":")[0].trim())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a working example. I hope this solves your problem.

**Approach:**

Grouping gives you map containing lists which you just need to sort by their sizes, then flatten them and finally collect as list.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Play {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("100 : 200",
                "200 : 207",
                "200 : 203",
                "200 : 201",
                "300 : 202",
                "103 : 201",
                "103 : 202");
        List<String> processedList = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(string -> string.split(":")[0].trim()))
                .values().stream().sorted((list1, list2) -> Integer.compare(list2.size(), list1.size()))
                .flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(processedList);
    }
}
```

You can try to remove redundant operators, if there are any. You can access your strings using the getter methods of your class and follow the approach as shown in the example.

Comment: Thanks, nice one mate. Stream hero :-)

Comment: Don’t use minus for reversing the result of a comparator. Since the magnitude of the returned value is unspecified, it could be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, in which case it, flipping the sign will fail. You can use `(list1, list2) -> Integer.compare(list2.size(), list1.size())` instead. Or `Comparator.comparingInt(List<?>::size).reversed()`. Or `Comparator.comparingInt(l -> -l.size())`, which is safe as the size of a list is never negative. And instead of `string.split(":")[0].trim()`, which populates an array with all unneeded substrings, you can use `string.replaceFirst("\\s*:.*", "")`.

Comment: No need to create an `ArrayList` as a copy of the list returned by `Arrays.asList`.

Answer (score 3):

Funny how your input data does not correspond with the actual samples from java code and you have accepted and answer that does not print the information in the format that you want: in your code you *want* entries, the accepted answer does a `List`...

But anyway considering your literal question the problem with your approach that once you did `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())` you "lost" the second part of `groupName` because of the previous `map`. You could use `Collectors::mapping` for that:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s:\\s");

    rules.stream()
         .map(CompatibilityRule::getGroupName)
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             x -> p.splitAsStream(x)
                   .findFirst()
                   .orElseThrow(),
             Collectors.mapping(
                 x -> p.splitAsStream(x).skip(1).findFirst().orElseThrow(),
                 Collectors.toList())
         ))
         .entrySet()
         .stream()
         .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(List<String>::size).reversed()))
         .flatMap(x -> x.getValue().stream()
                        .map(y -> new SimpleEntry<>(x.getKey(), y)))
         .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: The question doesn’t state that the end result has to be a list of `Map.Entry` instances; it only shows textual output. Besides—you can simplify the comparator like `.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(List<?>::size).reversed()))`

Comment: @Holger oh snap, good point. funny how Intellij does not compile `List<?>::size`, but does a `List<String>::size`

Comment: The `splitAsStream` approach is complicated and costly. I’d use something like `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\s:\\s(.*)", Pattern.DOTALL);` and `.map(CompatibilityRule::getGroupName)
 .map(p::matcher) .filter(Matcher::find)
 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.group(1), Collectors.mapping(m -> m.group(2), Collectors.toList())))`

Comment: @Holger indeed a lot more simple, but I don't think you need a non-greedy first group or `Pattern.DOTALL`

Comment: I was thinking about `\\s*:\\s*` where a greedy `(.*)` at the beginning would consume the white-space before the colon. To be behavioral identical to `split("\\s*:\\s*")`, we must use `DOTALL` to include everything, even when there were line breaks. It makes no difference for the sample input, but also means that the `(.*)` at the end could simply consume the rest of the string without looking at its content (at least in theory, it’s implementation dependent), whereas without it, the implementation must check whether there are line breaks (unlike us, it doesn’t know that there are none).

Comment: @Holger I still vaguely understand your point. it seems that you are referring to `(.*)\\s*:\\s*(.*)` _with_ `Pattern.DOTALL` and _without_ it. If so, I understand that those greedy modifies and the _absence_ of `Pattern.DOTALL` could consume everything after the second `\\s*` - even when there are line breaks. If that was your point - thank you, I understood that.

Comment: Two points. First, when you do `split(":")` (let’s simplify it), the matcher doesn’t care whether there are line breaks in what’s *not* matching the separator. When we reverse the approach to finding `(.*):(.*)` and using `group(1)` and `group(2)` we must use `DOT_ALL` to retain the logic of not caring about line breaks. The second point is about using `(.*)\\s*:` at the beginning. The greedy `.*` will consume everything up to the *last* `:` and `\\s*` always match an empty sequence, hence, we must use `(.*?)\\s*:` instead, to have `(.*?)` not consuming spaces before the the *first* `:`.

Comment: @Holger flawless! as usual (I take that for granted sometimes from you). I understand exactly what you meant. thank you again.